# Derivatives Must Exist over an Entire Open Set?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let the domain of some function $f$ be an open set that contains the point $a$. This question is with regards to the domain of the (partial) derivatives of $f$.

Claim: If all the partial derivatives of $f$ at $a$ exist, then all the partial derivatives exist in some open set containing $a$.

In other words, the (partial) derivative functions cannot have isolated points in its domain.

Is this true?

Comment: It is false, and Nitin showed you a perfect counter example. I would go ahead and accept his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 &\mbox{if } x \in \mathbb Q \\
0 & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$
is differentiable at $x = 0$ and discontinuous elsewhere (sequence definition of continuity helps here).

Note that for sufficiently small $x$,
$$\left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}\right| = \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \leq |x| < \varepsilon,$$
so $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks Nitin. So the domain of $f'(x)$ is a single isolated point at 0? Because a function is always continuous at isolated points, the derivative $f'(x)$ (in your example) is actually continuous at 0?

Comment: You are correct in saying that the domain of $f'(x)$ is a single isolated point $\{0\} \subset \mathbb R$, and yes, $f'(x)$ is continuous at 0, but rather trivially. Remember the graph of $f'$ is literally the point $(0,0)$ and nothing else, so it's not so meaningful to talk about continuity of a derivative there.

Comment: You should also be careful in making the leap: $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x$ implies $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x$. For another classic counterexample, consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x = 0 \end{cases}.$$
One appeals to product and chain rule for the derivative when $x \neq 0$ and the definition of derivative to see that $f'(0) = 0$. However, $f'(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to 0$, so we have that $f$ is differentiable at all points $x$, but $f'$ is not a continuous function.

Comment: If you're interested in more counterexamples related to differentiability, see: http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m555/10S/diff-counterexs.pdf
You can find the full book on the internet as well.

Comment: This is very helpful; thanks, Nitin. I was reading the calculus book by Stewart and advanced calculus book by Edwards, along with handouts Google pointed me to, but this chapter looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm reading advanced calc by Edwards at the moment too!